# Javassist parent classpool error when creating class within a classpool

Tags: java, kotlin, javassist

I've spent a while attempting to diagnose this issue and tinkering with Javassist. I'm trying to load a jar, identify the main class, load the jar as well as a certain file into the class pool, modify a function in the main class to use that loaded class, then replace the original jar. All meant to implement a sort of automatic updating. Yet, when I try to load a normal jar I get the following error "x is in a parent ClassPool. Use the parent."

```
private fun modifyFile(file: File) {
    val jar = JarFile(file)

    val (mainClass, mainMethod) = getMainClassAndMethod(jar)

    val fis = jar.getInputStream(jar.getEntry(mainClass))
    val pool = ClassPool(ClassPool.getDefault()).also {
        it.appendClassPath(file.path)
        // Add the extra class to the pool so we can use it
        it.appendClassPath(ClassClassPath(ClassAppender::class.java)) 
    }

    val cc = pool.makeClass(fis)

    val cm = cc.getDeclaredMethod(mainMethod)
    cm.insertBefore("{ Code to add... }")

    cc.defrost()

    fis.close()
    jar.close()

    saveJar(file, mainClass, cc.toBytecode())
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is an interesting question. I am sure that there will be someone looking into it, if you provide a little [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to play with. How about a minimal Maven project on GitHub? While I think I understand what you want to do from your good explanation, I really do not feel so inclined to create a project reproducing your situation from scratch.

Comment: @kriegaex right. Good point- will get on that.